# put(java.lang.String,java.lang.Inte ger) in java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer> cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Tags: java, hashmap

I am getting this error while compiling my code. Please help me with this-

code is

```
mapConnectionProperties = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        mapConnectionProperties.put(mobileSeriesMappingDTO
                                .getExternalIP(), mobileSeriesMappingDTO.getExternalPort());
```

Comment: Which error? What do getExternalIP() and getExternalPort() return?

Comment: Read the error: You are trying to pass two strings to a method that accepts a string and a integer as arguments

Comment: Looks like a very clear error message.

Comment: getExternalIP is retrieving string and getExternalPort is retrieving int. Both are retrieving correct data. Also, when I am compiling through eclipse it does not give error but when compiling through Ant it gives this casting error and shows compile failed

Comment: You should then verify your ant Script, looks like the MobileSeriesMappingDTO.class is not up to date.

Answer (score 2):

`mobileSeriesMappingDTO.getExternalPort()` is seemingly a `String`. Convert it to an `Integer`.

```
Integer.parseInt(mobileSeriesMappingDTO.getExternalPort())
```

Comment: or make the map a map of <String, String> so you don't need to.

Comment: Assuming the port refers to a networking port number, then it makes more sense to convert to an int. An int has far fewer invalid values to represent a port number than a String does.

Comment: Synesso is right... though it depends on context, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `mobileSeriesMappingDTO.getExternalPort()` gives a String,

Transform it to an Integer with :

```
Integer.parseInt(mobileSeriesMappingDTO.getExternalPort())
```

Comment: getExternalIP is retrieving string and getExternalPort is retrieving int. Both are retrieving correct data. Also, when I am compiling through eclipse it does not give error but when compiling through Ant it gives this casting error and shows compile failed.